# In Eclipse how I can view table content in the Latex Table View?

Tags: tables, texlipse, eclipse

I am using texlipse plugin to write the latex document. As you can see from the following figure [image: diagram] when you put a table and corresponding data, then you can see the data information in **Latex Table View**. My question is how you can see this in **Latex Table View** (circle marked)? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same question but unless you copied a screenshot don't understand what you're asking. You seem to have figured it out?!

Comment: @Hirek, I saw it one document showed in a blog, but don't know how I can show the table views as show in the screenshot.I don't have the source code and setup for this.

Comment: Have you used Window->Show View->Texlipse->LaTeX table view?

Comment: The problem is I can not see any table data on latex table view, latex table view does not populate with table data